# Docker_Error_Python_Couchdb sh: 1: docker: not found

Tags: python, docker, couchdb, ubuntu-17.10

I tried to run docker image but have this problem. All the files are saved in the directory "my_new_docker_build". This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.14
RUN mkdir /my_new_docker_build
WORKDIR /my_new_docker_build
ADD . /my_new_docker_build/
EXPOSE 5984
CMD ["python", "/my_new_docker_build/py_couchdb.py"]
```

And this is is my Python code cadded "py_couchdb.py":

```
from os import system

# Launch volume docker couchdb from command line
system("docker run --name my-couchdb -v /my/custom-config-dir:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d -d couchdb")

# Coudchdb visible in open world
system("docker run -p 5984:5984 -d couchdb")
```

Comment: It looks like the script is expected to run on the host, not inside the container.

Comment: could you run manually inside container instead of `python` file and check logs?

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you for your answer. Actually the scrips runs on the host, but I tried to lunch with docker... and it doesn't work...

Comment: Hi PPShein, I'd like to use this script because I would like to extend it in a python project.

Comment: That script needs to run on the host; it doesn't usually make sense to create a Docker image that will just launch other containers (it is much more difficult to run than just running `docker` commands on the host).  It might be better run as a shell script than a Python script.